# Raw text inside django template with basic formatting preserved

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to put a portion of raw text data or a text file inside a django template in a way that will preserve its basic formatting (line breaks and tabulation)?

Comment: This is an HTML question, not a Django one. Django has nothing to do with how text is rendered in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<PRE>` [does](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) the job good enough:

HTML tag `<PRE>` will output anything that's enclosed preserving line breaks and spaces. This HTML element is supported by most widely browsers and both HTML4 and HTML5.